# Manage security in variation site sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have problem to setup security and manage groups in sharepoint 2010, first, I have created web site and I put AD groups in visitor SHP native groups, I try to access to my site without problem, when active the variation on my Site (FR & EN), I can't access with all user in this group(Visitor), if I put the AD groups in contributor SHP groups, it works, I think that the security in variation root pages causes problem, how can I setup this.
thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved with this the solution:

> Finally - I figure out the solution without Contribute.
>
> Created a custom Visitor Permission Level and given permission on
>   "Browse Directories" also
>
> "Browse Directories  -  Enumerate files and folders in a Web site
>   using SharePoint Designer and Web DAV interfaces."
>
> Now all the users under the Visitor Group can see the publishing
>   sites.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c2dab00a-95e4-4723-b08a-8c5ce7f37919/sharepoint-2010-publishing-pages-access-denied-for-read-view-only-users?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious